# How to use Stanford NER in Python?

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition

I need to use Stanford NER. I write these codes but below error is received. what should I do to correct the codes.

**codes [Python]**

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

st = StanfordNERTagger('/C:/Users/PiXel/Dropbox/00 Phd semester 1/0 Natu langu processing/NLP-projects/0 summurizing project/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz','/C:/Users/PiXel/Dropbox/00 Phd semester 1/0 Natu langu processing/NLP-projects/0 summurizing project/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner.jar',encoding='utf-8')
text = 'While in France, Christine Lagarde discussed short-term stimulus efforts in a recent interview with the Wall Street Journal.'

tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)

print(classified_text)
```

**error**

```
LookupError: Could not find stanford-ner.jar jar file at /C:/Users/PiXel/Dropbox/00 Phd semester 1/0 Natu langu processing/NLP-projects/0 summurizing project/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner.jar
```

Comment: all of addresses are true

Comment: Could it be '/C:/Users'? This slash before C...

Answer (score 0):

The way I addressed to files was linux method, while I am using windows system.  "/" before "C:/..." must be removed

```
st = StanfordNERTagger('C:/Users/PiXel/Dropbox/00 Phd semester 1/0 Natu langu processing/NLP-projects/0 summurizing project/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz','C:/Users/PiXel/Dropbox/00 Phd semester 1/0 Natu langu processing/NLP-projects/0 summurizing project/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/stanford-ner.jar',encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `/` in front of path. just user `C:/Users/PiXel/Drop....` so on.